# Updating a ListView with SimpeExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, listview

The following Android-code fills a ListView with data via a SimpleExpandableListAdapter. Now I would like to update the data in the changeData method after the adapter is set  (e.g. replace the word Group with any other word). The problem is ExpandableListAdapter has no notifyDataSetChanged() method, so how do you update an expandable list? I tried to use BaseExpandableListAdapter instead, but the view did not update.

```
public class ExpandableList3 extends ExpandableListActivity {
    private static final String NAME = "NAME";
    private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";

    private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Map<String, String>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<List<Map<String, String>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            groupData.add(curGroupMap);
            curGroupMap.put(NAME, "Group " + i);
            curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");

            List<Map<String, String>> children = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                children.add(curChildMap);
                curChildMap.put(NAME, "Child " + j);
                curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN, (j % 2 == 0) ? "This child is even" : "This child is odd");
            }
            childData.add(children);
        }

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }
            );
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);


    }
    changeData();

}
```

Comment: I've never done an expandablelist with a hashmap... I've done it with cursors, and there it's as simple as re-querying the group cursor.  Looking through the docs for the ExpandableListAdapter, I find `registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer)` which is inherited from the base Adapter, and that says "Register an observer that is called when changes happen to the data used by this adapter.  Parameters - observer - the object that gets notified when the data set changes. "
Sounds like what you might need to use.